# How to deactivate facebook share button after click

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, share-button

is there some way to deactivate FB share button or mark it like "done" after sharinig content? Like button have two states which indicates if I "like" it or not. On the share button is not visible if I shared the content or not. Is there a way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i could think of is by authorizing a user with `publish_actions`. In that case, the response will be the new post id, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

BUT: You should not do something like that anyway. Let the user share stuff several times if he wants to. He may want to select different recipients for the share.